# Why is \input not expandable?

Tags: programming, expansion, input, latex-base

In `latex.ltx` I found `\def\input{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\@iinput\@@input}` where `\@@input`is expandable. I would like to know if there is an expandable version of `\input`.

The problem comes from an example with my package `alterqcm`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\newcommand*{\square}{\vbox{\hrule\hbox to 6pt{\vrule height 5.2pt \hfil\vrule}\hrule}}%  
%  \usepackage{fourier} % \square is defined with fourier
\usepackage{alterqcm}

\begin{document}
\begin{alterqcm} 
  \AQmessage{Soit $h$ la fonction telle que: $h:x\longmapsto x(x-1)$.}

  \AQquestion{Par cette fonction: L'image de}{
{4 est 8},
{0 est 2},
{8 est 4},
{2 est 0}
} 
\end{alterqcm}
\end{document}
```

Now it's possible to put the question in a file named 'question_1_2.tex'

```
  \AQmessage{Soit $h$ la fonction telle que: $h:x\longmapsto x(x-1)$.}    
  \AQquestion{Par cette fonction: L'image de}{
{4 est 8},
{0 est 2},
{8 est 4},
{2 est 0}
}
```

Now

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\newcommand*{\square}{\vbox{\hrule\hbox to 6pt{\vrule height 5.2pt \hfil\vrule}\hrule}}%  
\usepackage{alterqcm}

\begin{document}
\begin{alterqcm}       
\input{question_1_2.tex}
\end{alterqcm}
\end{document}
```

gives an error `\omit misplaced`. I need to write :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\newcommand*{\square}{\vbox{\hrule\hbox to 6pt{\vrule height 5.2pt \hfil\vrule}\hrule}}%  
\usepackage{alterqcm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ExpandableInput[1]{\@@input#1 }
\makeatother  

\begin{document}
\begin{alterqcm} 
\ExpandableInput{question_1_2.tex}
\end{alterqcm}
\end{document}
```

1) Is it possible to use another macro or version of `\input`?

2) Why does the error disappear if I put

```
 \begin{alterqcm} 
  ...
 \end{alterqcm}
```

inside `question_1_2.tex`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The LaTeX `\input` command, by Lamport's choice, must support both

```
\input{file}
```

and

```
\input file
```

so it's necessary to define it in that way: a test on the following character is necessary as the primitive `\input` scans its argument in a very peculiar way.

If you don't want to support the original syntax inside your environment, then putting

```
\def\input#1{\@@input #1 }
```

in the environment's definition is OK (unless a very devious user writes `\input file` inside the file that's input), and should not give problems of "Misplaced `\omit`".

The problem is caused by the fact that the `\input` file starts with `\AQmessage` that I understand is doing a `\multicolumn`: it's too late for it with the kernel definition of `\input`, because `\multicolumn` must come first in a table cell (it's `\omit`, actually, which is produced as the first token by `\multicolumn`); but the code for doing the business of `\input` is already there.

Why the problem does not show when the environment is inside `question_1_2.tex`? Well, the alignment begins inside the file, when `\input` has already done its service.

Comment: Perhaps you could add that `\omit` must appear as the first token in an alignment cell, after expansion.

Comment: Also, `\input` using LaTeX syntax will search for a file before trying to input it, which does not happen with TeX syntax. That is again non-expandable.