# Cannot use \toprule when doing \input inside tabular -- why?

Tags: tables, expansion, input

Using `\input` inside a `tabular` environment does not seem to work in all cases, but I don't see why.

The MWE below gives the following error message:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\toprule ->\noalign 
                    {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\abovetopsep \global \@b...
l.1 \toprule
```

File `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \input{inp}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

File `inp.tex`:

```
\toprule
a & b \\
c & d \\
\bottomrule
```

The document compiles properly if the contents of `inp.tex` are pasted into the `tabular` environment. What is happening here?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \toprule
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of compilation]

**EDIT**: The following question is related: [Why is \input not expandable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43006/why-is-input-not-expandable)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`\input` is trying to be intelligent, and this seems to be upsetting LaTeX's picky tabular definition.

But you can access the original `\input` primitive from TeX which is less dangerous at this point.

After defining

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\primitiveinput[1]
{\@@input #1 }
\makeatother
```

using `\primitiveinput` inside the tabular should work.

Comment: I would just prefer putting `\makeatletter\let\primitiveinput\@@input\makeatother` in the preamble and using it with `\primitiveinput imp\relax`. Calling your macro `\primitiveinput` is confusing: it is not the TeX primitive, but a macro that calls the primitive.

Comment: Of course you can use it in any way you prefer. But I think a more LaTeXy definition is less confusing to users. Additionally, your `\relax` would again disturb the tranquility of `tabular`, giving an error for `\primitiveinput inp\relax\midrule`. So the user would have to strictly adhere to leaving a space behind the file name, something which might not come naturally to LaTeX users...

Comment: Thank you, this seems reasonable. Is this related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43006/why-is-input-not-expandable ?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the same problem, only wrapped in an extremely long question ;-)

Comment: But then why on earth *call* it a primitive when it obviously isn't? By all means call it something else if that's better. LaTeX user or not, I'd rather you not call a spade a pitch fork.

Answer (score 4):

Some commands e.g. `\toprule`, `\hline` or `\multicolumn` must come directly at the start of a cell. There can't be anything before, this includes commands like `\input`.

Comment: Still, Stephan Lehmke show it is possible, becuase his solution works... ;-)

Comment: @tohecz, Both are right, it just depends when you look. `\omit` or `noalign` or `\span` must be the _first_ thing _after expansion_ (you need to allow expansion as none of the commands mentioned are primitive) the primitive `\@@input` is expandable so basicaly is not there according to this definition, but LaTeX's `\input` is not expandable and so leaves a token before the `\omit`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then this is not a solution but a comment ... :-/

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution for me. I had 1) `\begin{tabular}`, 2) `\small`, 3) `\toprule`. Moving 2 before 1 solved the problem for me. Thanks!