# Expandable version of \InputIfFileExists or \IfFileExists

Tags: tables, expansion, input

From this question: [Cannot use \toprule when doing \input inside tabular -- why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50694/8057) I know that everything inside the `tabular` environment should better be expandable. The MWE below suggests that `\InputIfFileExists` is not, although the error message is different now:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.8       \end{tabular}
```

File `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \InputIfFileExists{inp.tex}{}{}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

File `inp.tex`:

```
\toprule
a & b \\
c & d \\
\bottomrule
```

How do I check, in an expandable fashion, if a file exists and input it if it does?

The following question is related: [Why is \input not expandable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43006/why-is-input-not-expandable)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The check if a file exists is not expandable, because the file is opened using `\openin\somefilehandle=<filename>` which makes an assignment to `\somefilehandle`. Then `\ifeof\somefilehandle` is used to check if the end-of-file (EOF) is already reached, which is immediately true for non-existing files. Empty files, I think, need to be read at least once before EOF is reached. Assignments are not expandable, therefore the test isn't.
However, reading a whole file using TeX's `\input` (renamed to `\@@input` by LaTeX, while `\input` is redefined to an unexpandable form) does not require the assignment of an filehandle and therefore is expandable.

You could however, check if the file exists outside the `tabular` and have an fully expandable macro which includes the content if the file exists or does nothing else.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newif\ifmyfileexists
\makeatletter
\let\originput\@@input
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \IfFileExists{inp}{\myfileexiststrue}{\myfileexistsfalse}%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \ifmyfileexists
        \originput inp
      \fi
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

Or using some user level macros:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testfileexists}[1]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}%
    {\def\inputtestedfile{\@@input #1 }}
    {\let\inputtestedfile\@empty}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \testfileexists{inp}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \inputtestedfile
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

[image: Warning] <sup>*This is my first LuaTeX code, so please bear with me. `:)`*</sup>

For completeness sake, I'll add a LuaTeX solution, as Joseph mentioned in the comments. I believe the Lua code is self-explanatory.

Let's suppose I have a file `meow.tex` with the following content:

```
Hello cat!
```

And the file `mydoc.tex` :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
-- Checks if file exists.
function checkFile(theFile)

    -- open a file handler
    local fileHandler = io.open(theFile,"r")

    -- check if the handler is valid
    if fileHandler then

        -- the file exists, close
        fileHandler:close()

        -- print the input command
        tex.print("\\input{" .. theFile .. "}")

    end
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\myinput[1]{\luadirect{checkFile(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}

Hello world!

\myinput{meow.tex}

\end{document}
```

Running `lualatex mydoc.tex`, the following output is obtained:

[image: Cat]

Replacing `meow.tex` by `woof.tex` (which doesn't exist), we get the following output:

[image: Dog]

There we go, a nice fallback. `:)` We could even add an `else` branch in the Lua code to print a message about the missing file.

Comment: Mmm, I need a better file checking code in my `standalone` package for the automated build feature. Using Lua code like this might be the way (if LuaTeX is used of course). Do you now a way to get the full absolute path of the file or the full relative path from the current directory?

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I tried to find a way to get the full absolute path of the file, but it was quite complicated. The only solution I could find is a third-party pure Lua library named [Penlight](http://stevedonovan.github.com/Penlight/api/index.html) built on top of the [LuaFileSystem](http://keplerproject.github.com/luafilesystem/index.html) which happens to have an [`abspath`](http://stevedonovan.github.com/Penlight/api/modules/pl.path.html#abspath) function to get the absolute path of a file. To get the full path of the current directory, you could use `require 'lfs'` and `lfs.currentdir()`.

Comment: Dear downvoter, care to explain why my answer deserves your criticism? `:)`

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible as not all of the the underlying primitive used for the file check are expandable. In particular, the file check uses `\openin`, which is not expandable, although the actual test for end-of-file (`\ifeof`) is expandable.

You can use the `\input` primitive (stored by LaTeX2e as `\@@input`), which is expandable, but this cannot check for file existence. So this is only safe if the file is definitely available.

Comment: Note that a LuaTeX solution will be expandable as `\directlua` is, but I'm not sufficiently up on Lua to know the appropriate functions to use.