# Execute non-expandable code inside a tabular environment

Tags: tables, macros, tex-core, expansion

As there is no [Expandable version of \InputIfFileExists or \IfFileExists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50820/8057), the question arises whether it is possible to execute non-expandable code in a `tabular` environment after all:

File `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% How to implement this? %
\newcommand\InsideTabularInputIfFileExists[1]{...}
% How to implement this? %

% Do not change anything here %
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \InsideTabularInputIfFileExists{inp.tex}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
% Do not change anything here %
```

File `inp.tex`:

```
\toprule
a & b \\
c & d \\
\bottomrule
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to put unexpandable code in an `\noalign{..}` expression. The closing `}` can be added dynamically using a special trick, allowing a macro to insert code after the `\noalign` if the test inside it is true.

`\noalign` is used for material which should not be aligned with the tabular format, i.e. put into cells. All horizontal lines like `\hline` or `\toprule` are done using `\noalign`. You can use these only between rows, i.e. at the beginning of a row, which is in fact the source of your original problem. However, it is possible to have multiple `\noalign`s after each other.

The following defines a `\NoAlignInputIfFileExists{<filename>}` which can be used as you intended, but will create an error if not used between tabular rows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\NoAlignInputIfFileExists[1]{%
    \noalign{\ifnum 0=`}\fi
    \IfFileExists{#1}
        {\ifnum 0=`{\fi }\@@input #1 }%
        {\ifnum 0=`{\fi }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
      % must be used at the beginning of a tabular line, but
      % can be mixed with other \noalign commands like \hline etc.
      \NoAlignInputIfFileExists{inp}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

To explain this advanced code a little:
The `\noalign` boxes/executes its content while reading it. It doesn't read the `{..}` as an argument, so it doesn't look directly for the closing `}`. 
Here the `` \noalign{\ifnum 0=`}\fi `` trick is used. The `}` is actually removed because the `\ifnum` is false. However, the `\newcommand` sees both an opening `{` and closing `}` so is happy to have a matching number of them. The actual closing `}` for the `\noalign` exists twice: once for in each if/else-clause. An `` \ifnum 0=`{\fi } `` is used to remove the `{` during the execution of `\noalign`, which is again needed to be present to make the `\newcommand` definition happy.

Comment: Here you can simply use `\noalign\bgroup`, and `\egroup`, rather than the more elaborate `\ifnum0=\`}\fi`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Interesting. Why is ``\ifnum0=`}\fi`` then used again in `\hline` etc.? I think I knew it once, but it eludes me now.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I guess that one of the reasons is to manage `\hline\hline`.

Comment: @egreg.  Managing `\hline\hline` requires non-expandable lookahead, but this can be done with `\noalign\bgroup...` closed by `\egroup` in `\@xhline`.  The only case where this lookahead is risky is `\hline &`:  with the `\bgroup` version, the `\futurelet` picks up `\outer endtemplate:`, which by chance doesn't break anything.  When using the `\ifnum` trick, TeX's master counter is non-zero when futureletting `&`, hence we get `&`, not the end-template command.  This is safer (but that safety happens to be useless here).

Answer (score 4):

I believe that your needs can be accomplished more easily with a command, rather than with the explicit `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tabularinput}[2]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}
    {\begin{tabular}{#2}
     \@@input #1
     \end{tabular}}
    {INEXISTENT FILE #1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tabularinput{inp}{ll}

\tabularinput{xxx}{ll}
\end{document}
```

An "environment" version, which I don't recommend, can be a modified version of Martin's code:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\expinput}[1]{%
  \noalign{
    \IfFileExists{#1}
      {\gdef\expinput@temp{\@@input #1 }}
      {\gdef\expinput@temp{INEXISTENT FILE #1}}
   }\expinput@temp}
\makeatother
```

but I can't see how

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\expinput{inp}
\end{tabular}
```

is preferable to `\tabularinput{inp}{ll}`, unless the `\input` thing is only part of the tabular.

Comment: Well. The problem here is that `\begin{tabular}` is user code and `\@@input` is package code. So, the `% Do not change anything here %` is really, really meant to be :-)

Comment: @user946850 User code is what the package decides it to be. I'm convinced that using `\begin{tabular}{ll}\whateverinputcommand{file}\end{tabular}` is *wrong* user code.

Comment: Right. But why is this *wrong* user code?

Comment: @user946850 Because the `\begin{tabular}` and `\end{tabular}` are used where they don't belong. A "command" version allows for easier customization; for example you can redefine it to do nothing at all, which with the `tabular` version you can't.