# weird ifnum with compact syntax

Tags: tex-core, syntax

In some packages like `tabularx`, I find the following syntax in many places

```
{\ifnum0=`}\fi
```

or even

```
\ifnum0=`{\fi}
```

But I can't figure out why this can be useful for? Is `` ` `` a register of some kind? Or is it a TeX-hack to generate error on specific occasion ?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50828/execute-non-expandable-code-inside-a-tabular-environment

Comment: Perhaps take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9897/showcase-of-brace-tricks-egroup-iffalse-fi-etc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah the `\ifnum` funky brace groups beloved of TeX`\halign` programmers:-)

```
`
```

is part of the syntax for a *number* in TeX.

```
125
```

is a decimal

```
"7D
```

is hex and

```
`}
```

is the character code of the specified character (which is also 125 as it happens).

So....

```
{\ifnum0=`}\fi
```

the inner `\ifnum` is testing if 0=125 which is false so *when expanded*  this is equivalent
to `{` so starts a brace group.  However if the tokens are not being expanded and TeX is just looking for matching `{}` pairs then it sees that as a matching pair so you can go

```
\def\foo{  {\ifnum0=`}\fi }
```

but

```
\def\foo{  {  }
```

is an error (or at least does not stop at that `}`.

Usually you can use implicit brace groups `\bgroup` and `\egroup` to use an unmatched `{` but some constructs demand an explicit `{` token and so this trick (explained by Knuth in the TeXBook comes in useful).

Usually if you find that an environment that uses `&` to separate alignment cells does not work in a nested alignment it is because the author forgot to  use these groups in the definition.

Comment: I suppose than the second version I provided is for getting the `}`. "Funky brace groups" you said? :)

Comment: @M'vy Yes, the second one is the 'matching pair' here