# Only input file if it exists

Tags: conditionals, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expandable version of \InputIfFileExists or \IfFileExists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50820/expandable-version-of-inputiffileexists-or-iffileexists)

I am writing a LaTeX file where I input other LaTeX files (if and only if its exits, otherwise it should not include that file).

***** TFout_1.tex exist***********
***** TFout_2.tex doesn't exist***********

```
\documentclass{article}
%% Deutsche Anpassungen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{table}
\caption{ }
\begin{tabular}{l l}

 TAL& \input{./TFout_1.tex}  

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\centering

\InputIfFileExists{TFout_1.tex}
{
\begin{table}
\caption{ }
\begin{tabular}{l l}

\InputIfFileExists{TFout_1.tex}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

}

\centering
\InputIfFileExists{TFout_1.tex}
{
\begin{table}
\caption{ }
\begin{tabular}{l l}

\InputIfFileExists{TFout_2.tex}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Contents of file  TFout_1.tex:

```
\begin{small}\begin{tabular}{|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Datum}&\textbf{Grenzwert}&\textbf{Trend}\\\hline
06.12.2012 04:04&-20&Unterschritten\\\hline
06.12.2012 04:19&-20&Unterschritten\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{small}
```

Comment: Does this post help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50820/expandable-version-of-inputiffileexists-or-iffileexists?

Comment: @ hpesoj626 thanx.

Comment: @user31177, you could post the correct answer as an answer. This way the question and answer becomes better visible.