# How to check image exists or not?

Tags: graphics, conditionals, sweave, file-lookup

I'm working on Sweave and using `includegraphics` for include image in report dynamically.

Pseudocode:

```
 <<>
     for ( i to 100)   # run loop 1 to 100
     {
          includegraphics(image.i)    # include image in article.
     }
 @
```

In the above code I am adding 100 images using loop but I need to check that `image.i` exists or not first before including the image in report. Is there any way to check it first.

Comment: You can check this in LaTeX. See [Expandable version of `\InputIfFileExists` or `\IfFileExists`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50820/5764).

Comment: In `R`, you also have the function `file.exists()` that you can use in the chunk if you prefer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this into your preamble:

```
\newcommand\includegraphicsifexists[2][width=\linewidth]{\IfFileExists{#2}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}{}}
```

Then you can can safely use the following, the only problem is that you always have to add the extension:

```
\includegraphicsifexists[width=\linewidth]{nonexistingfile.pdf}
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------

You can make a version that makes a whole figure appear or not depending on the file presence (again, this goes to the preamble):

```
% arguments: [parameters for includegraphics]{filename}[float placement]{caption}
\makeatletter
\def\FIF@nopl[#1]#2#3{\IfFileExists{#2}{\begin{figure}\centering
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}\caption{#3}\end{figure}}{}}
\def\FIF@pl[#1]#2[#3]#4{\IfFileExists{#2}{\begin{figure}[#3]\centering
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}\caption{#4}\end{figure}}{}}
\newcommand\FigureIfExists[2][width=\linewidth]{\@ifnextchar[%
  {\FIF@pl[#1]{#2}}%
  {\FIF@nopl[#1]{#2}}%
}
```

Notice that I consider `[width=\linewidth]` as a good default argument to `\includegraphics` but you might change it of course. The usage is simple:

```
\FigureIfExists{myfile.pdf}[!t]{Caption of this nice figure.\label{fig:myfile}}

\FigureIfExists[scale=0.3]{nofile.pdf}[p]{This figure won't exist,
  nor the label.\label{fig:nofile}}
```