# Conditionally use package and define command

Tags: macros, packages, conditionals

I'm creating a class which should define a command if some package is available:

```
\IfFileExists{eforms.sty}{
   \usepackage[xetex]{eforms}
   \everyTextField{\textFont{GaramondNo8}\textSize{12}}
   \newcommand{\dsaTextInput}[3][12]{\raisebox{-0.35ex}{\textField[\textSize{#1}]{#2}{#3}{1em}}}
}{}
```

However, if I try to compile this, I get:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again>
                   1
l.7 }{}
```

`l.7` is the last line of the code I've shown. If I remove the conditional, it works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [Why do paramaters of `\renewcommand` need to double up the `#` within a `\foreach`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71632/5764).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to double the `#` symbols:

```
\IfFileExists{eforms.sty}{
   \usepackage[xetex]{eforms}
   \everyTextField{\textFont{GaramondNo8}\textSize{12}}
   \newcommand{\dsaTextInput}[3][12]{\raisebox{-0.35ex}{\textField[\textSize{##1}]{##2}{##3}{1em}}}
}{}
```

Why the doubling? Because the "true" and "false" branches are passed to `\def\reserved@a{<true>}` and `\def\reserved@b{<false>}`, so the usual rule applies.

See [What is the meaning of double pound symbol (number sign, hash character) ##1 in an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-1-in-an-argument) for more information

Answer (score 5):

Similar to answers like [Expandable version of \InputIfFileExists or \IfFileExists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50820/expandable-version-of-inputiffileexists-or-iffileexists)

```
\documentclass{article}
\IfFileExists{eforms.sty}{\def\x{T}}{\def\x{F}}
\if T\x%
   \usepackage{eforms}
   \everyTextField{\textFont{GaramondNo8}\textSize{12}}
   \newcommand{\dsaTextInput}[3][12]{\raisebox{-0.35ex}{\textField[\textSize{#1}]{#2}{#3}{1em}}}
\else
  \newcommand{\dsaTextInput}[3]{dsaTextInput Not Defined}
\fi
\begin{document}
\x
\dsaTextInput{10pt}{12pt}{Text}
\end{document}
```