# Table wrapper breaks when using svn-multi and booktabs

Tags: tables, booktabs, svn-multi

I have a bizarre problem with a customised table wrapper in conjunction with `booktabs` and `svn-multi`. The MWE below illustrates the issue.

The wrapper `myTable` works fine if:

- either `booktabs` is not used (comment `\bottomrule`)
- or the options `table,subgroups,groups` of svn-multi are not activated

But if both are used, I get the error:

```
Misplaced \noalign.
\bottomrule ->\noalign 
                       {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global...
\myTable{\input{tabletest.tex}}{4}{c}
```

To add to the confusion, if you just include all the information from the `\myTable` wrapper into the document and include the table content manually (and not via `\input`) **everything** works fine, with both `booktabs` and the `svn-multi` options.

Is something wrong with the `\myTable` command, or is that a bug in `booktabs`/`svn-multi`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[%
    table,subgroups,groups% Either one this together with booktabs breaks my custom-table command
    ]{svn-multi}

\begin{filecontents}{tabletest.tex}
label 1 & label 2 & label 3 & label 4 \\
item 1  & item 2  & item 3  & item 4  \\ 
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\myTable}[3]{%
\begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
#1%
\bottomrule%
\end{tabular}}%

\begin{document}

%This breaks if something from booktabs is included together with either one of the svn-multi options "table", "subgroups" or "groups" 
\myTable{\input{tabletest.tex}}{4}{c}

%This compiles fine although the content is identical to the one above.
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{4}{c}}%
label 1 & label 2 & label 3 & label 4 \\
item 1  & item 2  & item 3  & item 4  \\ 
\bottomrule%
\end{tabular*}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `\input` inside a `tabular` (or similar). `svn-multi` does execute some code at the begin and end of every file, which is here executed in the first cell of the `tabular`.
The error is caused because `\bottomrule` does not follow directly a `\\`, i.e. isn't at the begin of a cell, because some un-expandable code is inserted there by `svn-multi` with the used package options.

You can avoid this by using a different form of `\input`, i.e. use `\input tabletest.tex` (note the trailing space; `.tex` is optional) instead of `\input{tabletest}`. This uses the plain-TeX version of `\input` and bypasses the `svn-multi` code.

See also [Cannot use \toprule when doing \input inside tabular — why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50694/2975) which is very much related.

Comment: Yes, that solves the issue, thanks. I guess this could be closed as a duplicate (although I did my best to find an answer yesterday...).