# Use input inside a spreadtab environment with calculations

Tags: tables, expansion, input, calculations

My aim is to create a command for inserting tables, which will format the table, and add calculations on its values, given a file containing the raw data of the rows only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab,booktabs,xpatch}
\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{lcc}}
\toprule
@ Product name & @ Price & @ Count \\
\midrule
\input{products}
\midrule
@ Total & :={sumprod(b2:[0,-1];c2:[1,-1])} & sum(c2:[0,-1]) \\
\bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

where `products.tex` includes

```
@ Plant &  60 &  2 \\
@ Book  &  90 &  4 \\
@ Other & 100 & 10 \\
```

Pasting the lines of `products.tex` into the matching place above works smoothly.
[image: Table using raw text]

I wish to have the above code as a command, so I can use the same code to enter different table values, without repeating the heading and calculation definitions. However, the end result of using `input` always leaves the summation values as 0, and the `@` letter is now part of the text:

[image: Table after using input]

I guess the processing by spreadtab is done before the input is inserted - but I wonder if there is a way to solve it.

Following this question: [Cannot use \toprule when doing \input inside tabular -- why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50694/cannot-use-toprule-when-doing-input-inside-tabular-why), I tried to add primitive tex input into the spreadtab environment. Meaning, I used

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\primitiveinput[1]{\@@input #1 }
\makeatother
```

and replaced the line `\input{products}` with `\primitiveinput{products}`. But again no luck - I get the exact same output as using `input`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a complete, compilable example (Minimum Working Example) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` as this will make it much easier for people to help you effectively. Have you looked at [datatool](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) or [csvsimple](http://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple)? Perhaps one of those would help?

Comment: What are the constraints on the file input? Does it need to be in that format or are there other possibilities?

Comment: See the answer by @unbonpetit for the complete (trivial) example and the workaround solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to datatool and csvsimple packages - they look interesting for future use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a workaroud. All `\input{<name>}` are replaced by the file contents in the spreadtab environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{products.tex}
@ Plant &  60 &  2 \\
@ Book  &  90 &  4 \\
@ Other & 100 & 10 \\
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{spreadtab,booktabs,xpatch}
\makeatletter
\def\spreadtab@ii{\IfSubStr\ST@tab{\noexpand\input}{\expandafter\spreadtab@iii\ST@tab\@nil}\relax}
\def\spreadtab@iii#1\input#2#3\@nil{%
    \long\def\spreadtab@iv##1\spreadtab@iv{\endgroup\def\ST@tab{#1##1#3}\spreadtab@ii}%
    \begingroup
        \everyeof{\spreadtab@iv\noexpand}%
        \expandafter\spreadtab@iv\@@input#2
}
\xpretocmd\spreadtab@i\spreadtab@ii{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{lcc}}
    \toprule
    @ Product name & @ Price & @ Count \\
    \midrule
    \input{products}
    \midrule
    @ Total & :={sumprod(b2:[0,-1];c2:[1,-1])} & sum(c2:[0,-1])\\
    \bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me, thank you. If you could come up with a similar answer for a command instead of a file feel free to post your answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201109/textual-replacement-within-spreadtab?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks. Works great. Although I was hoping to get a more elegant answer (without the use of \makeat... commands).

Answer (score -2):

You have forgotten to include `\usepackage{booktabs}`.

Your code could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{lcc}}
\toprule
@ Product name & @ Price & @ Count \\
\midrule
@ product & 60 & 2\\
@ book    & 90 & 4 \\
@ pen     & 40 &10\\
@ other   &100 &10\\
\midrule
@ Total & :={sumprod(b2:[0,-1];c2:[1,-1])} & sum(c2:[0,-1])\\
\bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: spreadtab]

Comment: I don't think,that this is the answer to the question.

Comment: I agree with Christian. Maybe, you can have a look to pgfplotstable, which appears to be able to accomplish to OP requests and correct the answer.

Comment: I did not gave a complete latex code. Obviously, for booktabs commands to work one need to include this package. This was not the question.