# textual replacement within spreadtab

Tags: tables, macros

similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128692/use-input-inside-a-spreadtab-environment-with-calculations#) I want to use a function inside of a spreadtab region, but i do not want to use it out of a separate file but just simplify the usage and readability.

Unfortunately the usage of `\newcommand`, `\def` and `\edef` does not expand the text into the region and therefore the text is not recognized by spreadtab as normal.

My first idea would be to be able to make a textual macro such as in C-Programming by `#define`

The command that I currently have in the non-working state is this:

```
\newcommand*{\pos}[4]{ :={#1} &@ #2 &@ #3 & :={#4}\,\EUR & :={[-4,0]*[-1,0]}\,\EUR\\}
```

This would be exactly what I would want to insert into the spreadtab region. It corresponds to one line of the table. The output when using `pos` with

```
\pos{5}{text}{description}{10}
```

then is

```
:=5    @text    @description   10€       :=[-4,0]*[-1,0]€
```

instead of the expected line that I get when inserting the text directly into the spreadtab region:

```
5.00   text     description    10.00€    50.00€
```

Is there a possibility to create something like a C-Macro where the text is inserted before the 'compilation'? Or is there any other command I could use to simplify the usage without having to write all formatting issues again and again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tabular body contains `\+{<argument>}`, then the `<argument>` is expanded once:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{spreadtab,xpatch,eurosym}
\def\EUR{\geneuro}
\makeatletter
\def\spreadtab@ii{\IfSubStr\ST@tab{\noexpand\+}{\expandafter\spreadtab@iii\ST@tab\@nil}{}}
\def\spreadtab@iii#1\+#2#3\@nil{\edef\ST@tab{\unexpanded{#1}\unexpanded\expandafter{#2#3}}\spreadtab@ii}%
\xpretocmd\spreadtab@i\spreadtab@ii{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\pos[4]{ :={#1} &@ #2 &@ #3 & :={#4}\,\EUR & :={[-4,0]*[-1,0]}\,\EUR\\}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{*5c}}\hline
    \+{\pos{5}{text}{description}{10}}
    \+{\pos{9}{foo}{bar}{31}}\hline
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is almost great. Except when my LaTeX source file contains `\usepackage[whatever]{babel}`, all hell breaks loose with `Missing = inserted for \ifnum.`. Any idea to solve this ?

Comment: \edef\pos#1#2#3#4{ \string:={#1} &@ #2 &@ #3 & \string:={#4}\noexpand\,\noexpand\EUR & \string:={[-4,0]*[-1,0]}\noexpand\,\noexpand\EUR\noexpand\\}