# Adressing numeric field with newcommand within spreadtab

Tags: macros, spreadtab

I am using a spreadtab environment in a document to display a table with calculations. Since the commands are repeated for each row, I want to define a command via \newcommand that represents one row at a time. With this I hope that I can tidy up the code.

Unfortunately, the arguments of the command are always interpreted as the content of the text field. How can I define in \newcommand that an argument should be interpreted as a numeric field?

Below is a minimal example and an example of the basic idea of the command.

Thanks in advance,

BR
Christoph

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\nprounddigits{2}
\STsetdecimalsep{{,}}

\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|X|N{4}{2}|N{4}{2}}}
\hline
@\tiny Quantity & @\tiny Description & @\multicolumn{1}{r|}{\tiny Unit price} & @\multicolumn{1}{r}{\tiny Quantity * Unit Price} \\ \hline
3 & @Product 1 & :={2.5} \,EUR &:={[-3,0]*[-1,0]} \,EUR \\
\hline
2 & @Product 2 & :={5.5} \,EUR & :={[-3,0]*[-1,0]} \,EUR\\
\hline
3 & @Product 3 & :={1.0} \,EUR & :={[-3,0]*[-1,0]} \,EUR\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{@Total} & :={sum(d1:[0,-1])} \,EUR \\ \hline
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

Basic idea for the new command:

```
\newcommand{\newentry}[3]{#1 & #2 & #3 \,EUR & :={[-3,0]*[-1,0]} \,EUR \\ \hline}
```

In this case #1 should adress the numeric field. #3 and the 4th column with the product formular should adress the numeric and text field. #2 should adress the text field only.
A new entry in the table should be generated with \newentry{1}{Product 4}{25.00}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question, I found some question on this topic from the past. With the help of this topic, I was able to solve the problem: [textual replacement within spreadtab](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201109/textual-replacement-within-spreadtab?rq=1)

BR
Christoph