# TeX capacity exceeded with several \input in a spreadtab

Tags: errors, input, spreadtab, capacity

I use several `\input` in a `spreadtab` using the method from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207313/134574) in my document until I got this error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [text input levels=15].
```

I read in the Internet that I can manage the problem by changing the this parameter from `max_in_open = 15` to `max_in_open = 30`.

The problem I don't know where I can find the data to make the changes. I use TeXStudio on my Mac.

I am looking for the settings to make my document work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.8cm,top=2.8cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{spreadtab,booktabs,xpatch}
\usepackage[]{numprint}
\usepackage[]{eurosym}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx}
\usepackage{numprint}
}%=========================



\makeatletter
\def\spreadtab@ii{\IfSubStr\ST@tab{\noexpand\input}{\expandafter\spreadtab@iii\ST@tab\@nil}\relax}
\def\spreadtab@iii#1\input#2#3\@nil{%
    \long\def\spreadtab@iv##1\spreadtab@iv{\endgroup\def\ST@tab{#1##1#3}\spreadtab@ii}%
    \begingroup
    \everyeof{\spreadtab@iv\noexpand}%
    \expandafter\spreadtab@iv\@@input#2
}
\xpretocmd\spreadtab@i\spreadtab@ii{}{}
\makeatother    

\subsection*{B}
    \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{@{\hskip1pt}r@{\hskip7pt}p{2.7cm}crrr}}
    \toprule
    &@ Ku& @ Re & @ Ne & @ Me & @ Br \\
        \midrule
        \input{Bu1.txt}
        \input{Bu2.txt}
        \input{Bu3.txt}
        \input{Bu4.txt}
        \input{Bu5.txt}
        \input{Bu6.txt}
        \input{Bu7.txt}
        \input{Bu8.txt}
        \input{Bu9.txt}
        \input{Bu10.txt}
        \input{Bu11.txt}
        \input{Bu12.txt}
        \input{Bu13.txt}
        \input{Bu14.txt}
        \input{Bu15.txt}
        \midrule
        &@ To & @\thefo &(sum(d2:[0,-1]))tag(BN) & sum(e2:[0,-1])tag(BM)& sum(f2:[0,-1])tag(BB)\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{spreadtab}
```

Sample content of `Bu1.txt`:

```
@\thefoo&@BU1& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
```

The other `*.txt` look similar.

Comment: TeX can do arbitrarily many `\input` as long as they are not nested.  Do you really need more than 15 nested `\input`?

Comment: now I get to have to use more than 15 \input's

Comment: As I said, you can use thousands of `\input`s, as long as they are not nested.  With nested I mean a file `a.tex` that does `\input{b.tex}` that does `\input{c.tex}` that does `\input{d.tex}` that does...  If you change that to `a.tex` that does `\input{b.tex}\input{c.tex}\input{d.tex}`... it will work fine

Comment: actually the most I use for \input are *.txt and Its actually independent data. therefore I am confused why it is nasted inputs

Comment: Strange indeed, but with the information provided in the question is close to impossible to tell what the problem is.  Could you please show what your document looks like, and what's the structure of your project?  You can remove the contents of the file, as long as the `\input` commands remain where they are.

Comment: I add the code. If you want to know that the content of the *.txt is. I can add it too.

Comment: Yes, the contents of one of the files would be good (assuming they all look similar)

Comment: Full example please. There is no preamble or class listed in that example. Probably also a good idea to provide sample `.txt` files (you could just include the same `.txt` 15 times). Note: for something like this I'd probably use an external template engine to generate the table or what ever this is instead of using many inputs

Comment: `\everyeof{\spreadtab@iv\noexpand}%
    \expandafter\spreadtab@iv\@@input#2` is forcing every input file to execute input again at the end so it will loop forever and you will run out of input levels however many you allow. What do you intend this to do?

Comment: I created many *.tex with lots of Informations. So I thought about a tab that sums all information for me. Therefore my *.tex create *.txt and my tab get the Information through the \input

Comment: In MiKTeX you can provide [the command-line-option `--max-in-open=n`](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex-pdftex.html) when calling latex/pdflatex/xelatex/lualatex from the command-line. TeXLive: My system contains the file `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` where settings are done. That file, however, says that modifications that shall not be lost when updating should go to `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf.cnf`. So to `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf.cnf` you could add `max_in_open = 30        % simultaneous input files and error insertions, also applies to MetaPost`. But...

Comment: ... that won't be of any help because your code in any case recursively calls `\input`/`\@@input` until capacities are exceeded.

Comment: @UlrichDiez That sounds Good I can try it, maybe that helps me out. But did I have to Type the Terminal or how can I reach to texmf.cnf?

Comment: This is just a plain text file available when using the TeX-distribution "TeXLive". Open it with your favorite text editor. But again: This won't help you because your code recursively inputs the same file again and again without closing it in between until the capacity-exceeded-error is there. If you increase the value, then iteration takes a few more rounds until the capacity-limit is reached, that's all.

Comment: @IHPro I don't quite understand what you're trying to do.  You mention "tab" twice.  I'm used to tabs being piece of an html page.  Are you using "tab" as a short form of "table"?  Are you trying to have a "table that summarizes all information"?  How does your *.tex create *.txt?  Are you trying to `\input` individual rows and then have TeX create the summary row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As David pointed out in the comment, the code `\everyeof{\spreadtab@iv\noexpand} \expandafter\spreadtab@iv\@@input#2` is causing every `\input` to start yet another `\input` before finishing, which effectively nests inputs as far as TeX is concerned.

I don't really know `spreadtab`, so I don't have a good solution.  Instead, here is a very, very, very, very, very, very, *very*, *VERY* bad hack to make your document work.  The new `spreadtabwithinput` environment will replace every `\input{<file>}` command in its body by the contents of `<file>`, and then pass everything back to `spreadtab`.  You can have arbitrarily many `\input` in there.

Proceed at your own risk.

```
% \newwrite\wrt
% \def\x#1;{\immediate\openout\wrt"Bu#1.txt"
%   \immediate\write\wrt{@\noexpand\thefoo
%     &@BU#1& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\noexpand\\}%
%   \immediate\closeout\wrt
%   \ifnum#1<15 \expandafter\x\number\numexpr#1+1\expandafter;\fi}\x1;

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab,booktabs}

% HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK %
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__ihpro_spreadtab_hack_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ihpro_tmpa_tl
\NewDocumentEnvironment { spreadtabwithinput } { +b }
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l__ihpro_spreadtab_hack_tl
    \__ihpro_spreadtab_loop:w \prg_do_nothing: #1
      \input \q_recursion_tail \q_recursion_stop
    \exp_last_unbraced:Nno
    \begin{spreadtab}
      \l__ihpro_spreadtab_hack_tl
    \end{spreadtab}
  } { }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__ihpro_spreadtab_loop:w #1 \input #2
  {
    \tl_put_right:No \l__ihpro_spreadtab_hack_tl {#1}
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#2}
    \file_get:nnNF {#2} { } \l__ihpro_tmpa_tl
      {
        \msg_error:nnn { ihpro } { file-not-found } {#2}
        \tl_clear:N \l__ihpro_tmpa_tl
      }
    \exp_last_unbraced:NNo
    \__ihpro_spreadtab_loop:w \prg_do_nothing: \l__ihpro_tmpa_tl
  }
\msg_new:nnn { ihpro } { file-not-found } { File~'#1'~not~found. }
\ExplSyntaxOff
% HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK %

\newcounter{foo}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{B}
    \begin{spreadtabwithinput}{{tabular}{@{\hskip1pt}r@{\hskip7pt}p{2.7cm}crrr}}
    \toprule
    &@ Ku& @ Re & @ Ne & @ Me & @ Br \\
        \midrule
        \input{Bu1.txt}
        \input{Bu2.txt}
        \input{Bu3.txt}
        \input{Bu4.txt}
        \input{Bu5.txt}
        \input{Bu6.txt}
        \input{Bu7.txt}
        \input{Bu8.txt}
        \input{Bu9.txt}
        \input{Bu10.txt}
        \input{Bu11.txt}
        \input{Bu12.txt}
        \input{Bu13.txt}
        \input{Bu14.txt}
        \input{Bu15.txt}
        \midrule
        &@ To & @\thefoo &(sum(d2:[0,-1]))tag(BN) & sum(e2:[0,-1])tag(BM)& sum(f2:[0,-1])tag(BB)\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{spreadtabwithinput}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice explanation...

Comment: Though no nested `\input`s are possible this way.

Comment: @Skillmon That's what you get for using something advertised as `% HACK % HACK` :)  (and you also can't use `\input` inside braces)  Well, I guess I could add process the input contents with the same code...

Comment: @Skillmon What do you mean? Nested `\input`s work fine ;-)

Comment: +1 for the `% HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK % HACK %` :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik you're right, I must've misread the code :) Though from a coding point of view, why do the `\use_none:nn` (with the undocumented? behaviour of `\exp_last_unbrace:NNNNo` doing the right thing here), maybe it'd be better to put the second loop-instance into the false-branch. (I know historical growth)

Comment: I used your code and I get this as error:   'TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]. \end{spreadtab}'

Comment: @IHPro Can you upload the `.log` file to (say) https://pastebin.com/, please?

Comment: @Skillmon Right, indeed.  I made it a tad simpler. Thanks!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik sorry, the error is: File ended while scanning use of \ST@get@body@env.

Comment: @IHPro That's not much help.  I need the full `.log` file (and if you're not using the code exactly as I posted above, I need the code you are using as well), otherwise it is hard to guess what is causing the error

Comment: Yes you are right, now its work but its not sum up the numbers

Comment: @IHPro It should do the sum.  The way my code works is by inserting the contents of the files before `spreadtab` even starts, so for `spreadtab` it looks as if the table was typed in place.  Please show a compilable example of the non-working code

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik it works great, but there is one little mistake in your code I guess. I don't know why, but for a reason the last *.txt (\input{Bu15.txt}) doesn't show up and everything below is empty. So I have to copy the last *.txt and put above \end{spreadtabwithinput} than it works.

Comment: @IHPro Ah, indeed!  I got the order wrong of two lines of code and it was throwing away the contents of the table after the penultimate `\input` command.  It's fixed now

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik thank you very much, that give me another Solution for my problem, I appreciate your support!!!

Answer (score 1):

Off the cuff Heiko Oberdiek's package [catchfile](https://ctan.org/pkg/catchfile) comes to my mind.

You can use macros of this package for defining macros from the content of a file.

I can offer a routine

```
\CatchFilesForScantokens{⟨comma-separated file list⟩}{⟨preamble code⟩}{⟨postamble code⟩}
```

which reads and collects the *⟨preamble code⟩* and the content of each file of the *⟨comma-separated file list⟩* and the *⟨postamble code⟩* in verbatim-catcode-regime and then passes collected/accumulated things to `\scantokens` so that normal catcode-régime is in effect when the verbatimized material gets re-tokenized.

You can use this routine as

```
\CatchFilesForScantokens{⟨comma-separated file list⟩}%
                        {⟨stuff for initiating spreadtab-environment}%
                        {⟨stuff for ending the spreadtab-environment⟩}
```

*(Internally with each file of the *⟨comma-separated file list⟩* the routine uses the `\CatchFileDef`-macro of the package [catchfile](https://ctan.org/pkg/catchfile) for (re)defining a scratch-macro A from the content of that file, tokenized in verbatim-catcode/category-12-régime, and then appends the expansion of that scratch-macro A to the definition of another scratch-macro B. *⟨preamble code⟩* and *⟨postamble code⟩* also go to that other scratch-macro B. Thus everything is accumulated in that other scratch-macro B whose expansion can be passed to `\scantokens` for re-tokenization under normal catcode-régime.*

*I am lazy, so I use expl3's function `\clist_map_inline:nn` for parsing the *⟨comma-separated file list⟩*)*.

Here is the example:

```latex
% Create  15 MyBu<X>.txt-files
% ==========================
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu1.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU1& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu2.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU2& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu3.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU3& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu4.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU4& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu5.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU5& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu6.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU6& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu7.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU7& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu8.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU8& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu9.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU9& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu10.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU10& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu11.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU11& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu12.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU12& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu13.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU13& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu14.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU14& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyBu15.txt}
[0,-1]+1&@BU15& @513& 270.00& 551.30& 3231.30\\
\end{filecontents*}


% ==========================================================================================
% Define macro 
%
%   \CatchFilesForScantokens{<comma-separated file list>}{<preamble code>}{<postamble code>}
%
% to read and collect <preamble-code> and each file of <comma-separated file list> and 
% <postamble code> in verbatim-catcode-regime and to pass collected things to \scantokens:
% ==========================================================================================
\RequirePackage{catchfile}
\newcommand\MyScratchmacroA{}%
\newcommand\MyScratchmacroB{}%

% Within a local scope temporarily change the catcode-régime:
\begingroup
%
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
%
% We won't need \makeatother / \ExplSyntaxOff as -- like the other changes to the
% catcode-régime -- the effects of  \makeatletter and \ExplSyntaxOn will be gone
% when the local scope is closed by \@firstofone.
%
% Use the SOH(=Start Of Heading)-character, code-point-number 1 in ASCII, accessible
% as ^^A in TeX's ^^-notation, for commenting:
\catcode`\^^A=14 %
% Make the CR(=Carriage-Return)-character, code-point-number 13 in ASCII, accessible
% as ^^M in TeX's ^^-notation, an ordinary character --- every line must end by something
% that is taken for a comment-character by TeX as long as this setting is in effect :
\catcode`\^^M=12\relax%
% Make % an ordinary character:
\catcode`\%=12\relax^^A
^^A
\@firstofone{^^A
  ^^A the first thing \@firstofone shall do is close the local scope where the
  ^^A catcode-régime is changed:
  \endgroup^^A
  ^^A=============================================================================
  ^^A PARAPHERNALIA:
  ^^A \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
  ^^A=============================================================================
  \newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}^^A
  \newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}^^A
  \@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}^^A
  ^^A-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^^A Check whether argument is empty:
  ^^A.............................................................................
  ^^A \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
  ^^A                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
  ^^A                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
  ^^A                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
  ^^A                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
  ^^A
  ^^A The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
  ^^A <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{^^A
    \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter^^A
    \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter^^A
    \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter^^A
    \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{^^A
    \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}^^A
  }^^A
  ^^A-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^^A Check whether_verbatimized_ argument has a trailing explicit 
  ^^A <carriage-return>-character-token of catcode 12(other):
  ^^A-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^^A \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
  ^^A                                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case
  ^^A                                       <argument which is to be checked>'s
  ^^A                                       last token is an explicit <carriage-
  ^^A                                       return>-character-token of 
  ^^A                                       catcode 12(other)>}%
  ^^A                                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case
  ^^A                                       <argument which is to be checked>'s
  ^^A                                       last token is not an explicit
  ^^A                                       <carriage-return>-character-token of 
  ^^A                                       catcode 12(other)>}%
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn[1]{^^A
    \UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn#1\UD@SelDom^^M\UD@SelDom\UD@@SelDom^^A
  }^^A
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn{^^A
    \long\def\UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn#1^^M\UD@SelDom#2\UD@@SelDom{^^A
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2}{\UD@secondoftwo}{\UD@firstoftwo}^^A
    }^^A
  }^^A
  ^^A=============================================================================
  \NewDocumentCommand\CatchFilesForScantokens{m}{^^A
    \begingroup^^A
    \let\do\@makeother^^A
    \do\^^I^^A
    \CatchFilesForScantokensInner{#1}^^A
  }^^A
  \newcommand\verbatimregime{^^A
    \let\do\@makeother^^A
    \dospecials^^A
    \do\^^I^^A
    \do\^^M^^A
    \endlinechar=`\^^M\relax^^A
    \newlinechar=\endlinechar^^A
  }^^A
  \NewDocumentCommand\CatchFilesForScantokensInner{m+v+v}{^^A
    \endgroup^^A
    \begingroup^^A
    \edef\MyScratchmacroB{^^A
      \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}^^A
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}}^^A
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\detokenize{#2^^M}}}^^A
    }^^A
    \clist_map_inline:nn{#1}{^^A
      ^^A\message{##1^^J}^^A
      \CatchFileDef{\MyScratchmacroA}{##1}{\verbatimregime}^^A
      \edef\MyScratchmacroB{^^A
        \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\MyScratchmacroB\detokenize\expandafter{\MyScratchmacroA}}^^A
      }^^A
    }^^A
    \edef\MyScratchmacroB{^^A
      \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\MyScratchmacroB\detokenize{#3}%}^^A
    }^^A
    \newlinechar=\endlinechar^^A
    ^^A=======================================================================
    ^^A If you want to see on connsole what \scantokens gets as spreadtab,
    ^^A then enable the next but one line by removing the leading ^^A
    ^^A=======================================================================
    ^^A\show\MyScratchmacroB^^A
    \scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter\endgroup\MyScratchmacroB}^^A
  }^^A
}%


% Create  document:
% =================
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.8cm,top=2.8cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{spreadtab,booktabs,xpatch}
\usepackage[]{numprint}
\usepackage[]{eurosym}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx}
\usepackage{numprint}

\begin{document}

\CatchFilesForScantokens{%
  MyBu1.txt, 
  MyBu2.txt,
  MyBu3.txt,
  MyBu4.txt, 
  MyBu5.txt,
  MyBu6.txt,
  MyBu7.txt, 
  MyBu8.txt, 
  MyBu9.txt, 
  MyBu10.txt,
  MyBu11.txt,
  MyBu12.txt, 
  MyBu13.txt, 
  MyBu14.txt, 
  MyBu15.txt
}%
{%
  \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{@{\hskip1pt }r@{\hskip7pt }p{2.7cm }crrr}}
  \toprule
  &@ Ku& @ Re & @ Ne & @ Me & @ Br \\ % <- This is row 1.
  \midrule
  \SThiderow 0&&&&&\\ % <- This is row 2 and it is invisible and used for initial values.
}%
{%
  \midrule
  &@To & [-2,-1] &(sum(d3:[0,-1]))tag(BN) & sum(e3:[0,-1])tag(BM)& sum(f3:[0,-1])tag(BB)\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{spreadtab}
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

!!! This approach is based on reading/tokenizing files in verbatim-category-code-régime. Hereby `\input`-commands occurring within some of the files of the *⟨comma-separated file list⟩* will not be carried out. I.e., `\input`-nesting is not possible. All you can do is provide a list of files. !!!

!!! Also it is relied on reading and tokenizing the *⟨preamble code⟩* and the *⟨postamble code⟩* in verbatim-category-code-régime. This in turn implies that `\CatchFilesForScantokens`

- cannot be hidden inside the definition of whatsoever macro and
- cannot be used inside macro-arguments, i.e.,
- must be used in ways where it is ensured that the arguments will be obtained by reading and tokenizing things from the .tex-input-file while the changes of the category-code-régime temporarily introduced by `\CatchFilesForScantokens` are in effect.

!!!

Comment: thank you very much for your support, but it don't work and I even try to read the paper. however I didn't work.

Comment: @IHPro On my system (TeX Live 2020) the example compiles without error-messages. What exactly does not work when you try compiling? What error-messages do you get? In which way does the output deviate from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

On many TeX distributions there exists a file called texmf.cnf. It is located typically in `texmf/web2c` and contains the mentioned parameter. Usually it is not recommended to mess with this kind of configuration files. However, if your TeX supports this option it can be set on the command line with the switch `--cnf-line='max_in_open=30'`, e.g.:

`lualatex --cnf-line='max_in_open=30' some-file.tex`

Many editors support special command lines for projects or single TeX files. E.g. GNU Emacs supports to add a file local variable named `TeX-command-extra-options: "--cnf-line='max_in_open=30'"` so that the end of your TeX file could look like:

```
% mode: latex
% TeX-master: t
% TeX-command-extra-options: "--cnf-line='max_in_open=30'"
% End:
```