# Combining collcell with input

Tags: input, collcell

The following code works perfectly:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

 %The min, mid and max values
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0.0}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{0.5} %
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.0}%

%Apply the gradient macro
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
        \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
            \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{green!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}
        \else
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
            \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{red!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}
        \fi
}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm} % box size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{R}}
              0.03 & 0.34 & 0.41 & 0.25 & 0.89 & 0.49 & 0.79 & 0.83 & 0.82 & 0.94 \\    
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When I edit the code above to extract the data from a file rather than directly in the code, it doesn't!

```
    . . . 
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{*{10}{R}}
    \input{"data.tex"}  
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{table}
    . . .
```

If I change the column type from R to c, it compiles with no errors but something in the macro is not working when the data is in a separate file. The contents of the data.tex file are as follows:

```
  0.03 & 0.34 & 0.41 & 0.25 & 0.89 & 0.49 & 0.79 & 0.83 & 0.82 & 0.94 \\
```

How can I find a workaround to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `\input` is not expandable and this blocks the expansions that are needed before the `collcell` feature can work, so basically everything in the input file ends up in the first column, which of course will not work. See [Why is \input not expandable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43006/why-is-input-not-expandable) for more information.

Use the expandable version of `\input`, that is, the primitive that's saved by LaTeX in `\@@input`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
0.03 & 0.34 & 0.41 & 0.25 & 0.89 & 0.49 & 0.79 & 0.83 & 0.82 & 0.94 \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

 %The min, mid and max values
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0.0}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{0.5} %
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.0}%

%Apply the gradient macro
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
  \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{%
      max(min(100.0*(#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)
     }%<---- fixed
    \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{green!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}%<---- fixed
  \else
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{
      max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)
    }%<---- fixed
    \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{red!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}%<---- fixed
  \fi
}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm} % box size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xinput}[1]{\@@input #1 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{R}}
0.03 & 0.34 & 0.41 & 0.25 & 0.89 & 0.49 & 0.79 & 0.83 & 0.82 & 0.94 \\    

\xinput{\jobname.dat}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I used `filecontents` and `\jobname.dat` just not to clobber my files, you can pass any file name you want.

I also fixed some spurious spaces you had in the code.

[image]