# How to 'robustly' use file contents in command arguments?

Tags: external-files, filesystem-access, write

I have the following code which sets up a XeLaTeX document (to be run with `--enable-write18`) and defines two commands, `\showme` and `\prRaise`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{catchfile}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand*{\showme}[1]{The value is #1.}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter%
\newdimen\pr@Height%

\newcommand{\prRaise}[2]{%
  \setlength{\pr@Height}{\f@size pt}%
  \raisebox{#1\pr@Height}{#2}%
  }%

\makeatother%

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\cxltxReadA{\CatchFileEdef{\cxltxR}{/tmp/CXLTXtempout.tex}{}}
\def\cxltxReadB{\CatchFileEdef{\cxltxR}{/tmp/CXLTXtempout.tex}{}\cxltxR}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\showme{foobar}% => ”The value is foobar”.

\showme{\cxltxReadB}% => ”The value is -0.2 .”

\showme{\input{/tmp/CXLTXtempout}}% => ”The value is -0.2 .”

\showme{\immediate\input{/tmp/CXLTXtempout}}% => ”The value is -0.2 .”

A\prRaise{-0.2}{B}C% => "ABC" with B lowered

A\prRaise{-0.2 }{B}C% => "ABC" with B lowered (trailing space shouldn't be a problem)

A\prRaise{\input{/tmp/CXLTXtempout}}{B}C% !!! => Missing number, treated as zero.

A\prRaise{\immediate\input{/tmp/CXLTXtempout}}{B}% !!! => Missing number, treated as zero.

A\prRaise{\cxltxReadB}{B}C% !!! => Missing number, treated as zero.

\cxltxReadA A\prRaise{\cxltxR}{B}C% works

\end{document}
```

The thing is, trying to use the file contents with `\input`, `\immediate\input` and `\cxltxReadA` ... `\cxltxR` works for both commands, but, crucially, all attempts to read the file contents *within* the argument to `prRaise` fail. It'd be great if it did work, because what i really want to do is call some external program to do a contextual computation, so i want to call that external program at exactly the point where i need it.

Why do the two commands behave so differently? What in the definition of `\prRaise` causes these troubles?

Comment: Just for comparison. When you are using TeX (or XeTeX, but not LaTeX) then it is sufficient to write `A\raise\input file.tex em\hbox{B}C` instead of your `\prRaise`. LaTeX brings only complications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in [Why is \input not expandable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43006/why-is-input-not-expandable), the LaTeX version of `\input` is not expandable. To use `\input` in the context you'd like to, as part of setting a length, you need everything to work by expansion. There are good reasons why LaTeX's `\input` is defined the way it is, but if you really need expansion use the saved TeX primitive:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.tmp}
-0.2
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newlength\pr@Height
\newcommand\prRaise[2]{%
  \setlength\pr@Height{\f@size pt}%
  \raisebox{#1\pr@Height}{#2}%
}
\let\normalinput\@@input
\makeatother
\begin{document}
A\prRaise{\normalinput \jobname.tmp }{B}C
\end{document}
```

Note that the same issue applies to *e.g.*

```
A\prRaise{\cxltxReadB}{B}C%
```

as `\cxltxReadB` is trying to carry out a definition, which is again not expandable.

Comment: What are those good reasons? I thought the only thing was making it to understand both “syntaxes”: TeX `\input file` and LaTeX `\input{file}`.

Comment: @Manuel Try using the primitive with an incorrect file name, then try the same with the LaTeX version. In particular, imagine you are doing this 20+ years ago on a session taking several minutes per page where 'bail out' with a incorrect name is not a good option and some form of graceful recover is better!  (The 'look ahead' for `{` breaks expandability in any case.)

Comment: @Manuel In case you miss it :-) What you'll find is that with the primitive you are basically stuck: either you have to be able to sort out the file name or kill the run. With the LaTeX version you can skip the loading entirely and just 'push on': as I say, important in the past.

Comment: @Manuel The LaTeX version also knows about `\input@path`.

Comment: @JosephWright "you have to be able to sort out the file name or kill the run" ... this is not exactly true. You can type "null" and go on. Because there exists an empty file `null.tex` in TeX distributions.

Comment: @wipet I'd argue having 'just press enter to skip' is more natural/user friendly, but your point is of course valid.

Comment: is that true, we have to put up with this expandable / not expandable conundrum just because LL thought that 'hey, this is 1984, let's not type `null` any more, just hit enter'!?

Comment: @flow As noted, the LaTeX syntax for `\input` requires braces (as with essentially all LaTeX mandatory arguments). However, LaTeX also allows the primitive syntax and that is used _a lot_. The two cases can't be tested for expandably, sot this cannot be changed. Also, as I've noted, the LaTeX version makes use of `\input@path` which is then used for example by `\includegraphics`/`\graphicspath`. That again cannot be fully implemented in an expandable manner.

Comment: @flow As documented for LaTeX there is no reason to think `\input` can be used in anything other than non-expansion contexts. (I note that ConTeXt also makes `\input` non-expandable: it's not just LaTeX!) I'd ask how often in a structural sense it's necessary to use `\input` in an expansion context: I'd expect configuration or similar files to be written either to be executed (like the `.aux` file) or parsed (using `\read`/`\readline`) in almost every case.

Comment: this thinking permeates this culture. reading from a file is one of the few ways for TeX to communicate to outside processes, but that gets easily dismissed. quoting a precedent: "Neither Donald Knuth nor Leslie Lamport seems to have given much thought to the case where the paragraph skip has a positive natural width. Leslie Lamport dismisses all potential difficulties with the remark that 'it is customary not to leave any extra space between paragraphs'."—Victor Eijkhout, TUGboat 4/1990. makes me crazy when i ask how to put vertical rules into a table and people scream "you don't do that".

Comment: @flow I didn't say reading from secondary files was out, though at (La)TeX is a typesetting system there is some argument in terms of having the _content_ well-defined and self-contained. You can happily read from a file in a variety of ways, most obviously by arranging them to read in the form `\def\foo{setting}` as is done for example by the `.aux` mechanism, also by using as I say `\read` on a line-by-line basis or indeed using `catchfile` (more recent). As I say, the position is this behaviour cannot be changes in LaTeX2e (stability): design decisions for LaTeX3 are one for chat!

Answer (score 3):

First of all let's get rid of `\immediate`, which makes sense only before `\write`, `\openout` and `\closeout`, because these operations are normally performed during shipout and with the `\immediate` prefix they are performed “immediately”.

So `\immediate\input` has just one effect, that of expanding `\input` until the first unexpandable token is found. Since this token is `\let` (resulting from `\@ifnextchar`), TeX ignores `\immediate` and moves on.

I would distinguish your calls of `\prRaise` between an “explicit” argument and a file to be read in.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.tmp}
-0.2
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\prRaise{smm}
 {
  \dim_set:Nn \l_flow_pr_height_dim { \use:c { f@size } pt }
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% \tl_set_from_file:Nnn is the same as \CatchFileDef
    \tl_set_from_file:Nnn \l_flow_pr_factor_tl { } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_flow_pr_factor_tl { #2 }
   }
  \flow_pr_raise:n { #3 }
 }

\dim_new:N \l_flow_pr_height_dim
\tl_new:N \l_flow_pr_factor_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \flow_pr_raise:n #1
 {
  \raisebox{ \l_flow_pr_factor_tl \l_flow_pr_height_dim } { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
A\prRaise{-0.2}{B}C

A\prRaise*{\jobname.tmp}{B}C
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your effort... one more piece to demonstrate that doing TeX is more of an art than a science. this looks like black magic to me.