# Consuming variable's value (produced from shell call) as `\input`

Tags: input, shell-escape

Note: `\input` is not expandable: [Why is \input not expandable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43006/why-is-input-not-expandable)
However, `\@@input` is.

The goal is to `\@@input` some text produced from a shell call, obtained via `\sys_get_shell:nnN` (for how, see `egreg`'s answer on [Write18: capturing shell (script) output as command/variable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16790/write18-capturing-shell-script-output-as-command-variable)).
For example, a shell call may produce output `\A\B\C\D`, which we want to insert into the input stream since the document defines these commands.
The result of `\sys_get_shell:nnN` is saved into a variable `\result`, so we want to pass that variable, expanded, to `\@@input`.
We can use `\exp_args:Ne\@@input{\result}` to expand `\result` before calling `\@@input`.

In order to `\@@input` something, you can either read from a file `\@@input"my_file"`, or from the output of a shell command: `\@@input"|my_shell_command_here"`.

In order to avoid writing to a temporary file, I'd like to use the shell `|` option.
Thus we could just `|echo \result`.
However, this wouldn't have the desired effect: in a shell command, `\` is an escape character, so `echo` wouldn't print out exactly what we want, if it contains `\` (or other shell-special other tokens like `(`).

My next idea was to protect every character passed to the shell with a `\`, which would seemingly have the desired result. If `\result`=`\A\B\C\D`, we pass `\\\A\\\B\\\C\\\D` to the shell:

```
$ echo \\\A\\\B\\\C\\\D
\A\B\C\D
```

To perform this mapping, we can use `\tl_analysis_map_inline:nn` (or `\str_map_inline:nn`?) to prepend every token with `\`:
`\tl_analysis_map_inline:nn{\result}{\c_backslash_str#1}`

For sake of example, let's assume that the shell output is:

```
hi
ho
\A\B\C\D
\A\B\C\D
```

so a full attempt looks like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\A}{myA}
\newcommand{\B}{myB}
\newcommand{\C}{myC}
\newcommand{\D}{myD}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\expandableinput}[1]{ \@@input #1 }
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\inputfromecho} {m} {
   \expandableinput{"|echo~hi~&&~echo~ho~&&~echo~#1~&&~echo~#1"}
 }
 \NewDocumentCommand{\inputexpand} {m} {
 % Force expand #1 before calling \@@input
  \exp_args:Ne\inputfromecho{#1}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\sampleShellOutput} {} {
  \tl_analysis_map_inline:nn{ABCD}{\c_backslash_str##1}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\backslashProtectedShellOutput} {} {
  \exp_args:Ne\tl_analysis_map_inline:nn{\sampleShellOutput}{\c_backslash_str##1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

Shell output:\\
\sampleShellOutput

Shell output as input:\\
\inputexpand{\backslashProtectedShellOutput}

\end{document}
```

However, this produces errors on the last 2 `&`s, and continuing, output:

```
  Shell output:
“A“B“C“D
  Protected shell output:
““A“B“C“D
  Shell output as input:
hi ho
  ““A“B“C“D echo ““A“B“C“D”
```

We also see from the console log that the shell command actually run was:
`|echo hi && echo ho && echo` 
even though we expected to run:
`|echo hi && echo ho && echo \\\A\\\B\\\C\\\D && echo \\\A\\\B\\\C\\\D`

It seems like the `\` print as `"`, and also match against `"` to finish the `\@@input`, cutting off the shell command in the middle.

Without `"` surrounding the shell command, `\@@input` seems to stop parsing the shell command at the first space.

Is there a simpler (or any successful) way to input a variable's fully-expanded contents as `\input`?

Comment: Sorry, but it's really unclear what's the aim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what the intention of the expansion control in the question is. I think there is confusion between expanding the argument of `\input` and expanding the returned tokens.

If you save the following as `testcmd`

```
echo hi
echo ho
echo '\A\B\C\D'
echo '\A\B\C\D'
```

and make it excutable;

```
$ chmod a+x ./testcmd
```

(on windows you could make an equivalent `testcmd.bat`)

Then on the command line the command has the suggested output:

```
$ ./testcmd 
hi
ho
\A\B\C\D
\A\B\C\D
```

So to call that from latex use

```
pdflatex --shell-escape file
```

where `file.tex` is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\makeatletter
\def\shellcmd#1{\@@input"|#1" }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\A}{myA}
\newcommand{\B}{myB}
\newcommand{\C}{myC}
\newcommand{\D}{myD}

\shellcmd{./testcmd}

\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

---

The above answers the question in the title re interpretting the output of a shell call, but in comments you indicate an unrelated question, interpretting a tex token list as tex input, which I show below.

---

```
\documentclass{article}



\newcommand{\A}{myA}
\newcommand{\B}{myB}
\newcommand{\C}{myC}
\newcommand{\D}{myD}

\edef\var{hi
ho
\string\A\string\B\string\C\string\D
\string\A\string\B\string\C\string\D
}

\begin{document}

\verb|\var| character tokens: \texttt{\var}

Re-interpret \verb|\var| as \TeX: \scantokens\expandafter{\var}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The goal is to read an existing variable's value (after full expansion) as TeX input.

For example, we have a variable whose value after full expansion is the string \A\B\C\D (note that all 8 characters, including the backslashes, are separate tokens with character code 11).

We want to read these characters as LaTeX input, producing 4 tokens: \A \B \C \D.

We don't know what the full expansion of the variable is going to be, so I'm looking for a general solution that expands some variable, then processes the resulting text as LaTeX input.

Comment: @DavidFink but that is completely unrelated to \{nput basically you are describing \scantokens. your existing question as far as can be understood is asking about using the `|` pipe syntax to input the output of a command available on the operating system command line

Comment: @DavidFink I added a second answer

Comment: awesome, \scantokens is exactly what I was looking for. The searchability of this question is tough - hopefully some keywords like "reinterpret as raw LaTeX input" will lead people to this page.